# Como puedo crear una cola en memoria con C#

Tags: c#, .net, estructuras-de-datos, manejo-de-memoria, ram

Tengo actualmente un inconveniente en el cual se me presenta la opción de generar una cola en RAM para que los datos que ingresan en ella puedan ser procesados y utilizados de manera rápida sin que hayan llegado a la BD aún.

En mi trabajo usamos C# como lenguaje principal y me gustaría saber si existen librerías o algún tipo de herramienta de .NET para poder generar y controlar esta información en una cola de RAM?

En caso de que no sea posible, cual es la recomendación que me brindan? El problema que tengo es que dos registros idénticos no pueden ser procesados en un cierto lapso de tiempo, pero si ambos registros entran al mismo tiempo gracias a los hilos de las BD, ambos son procesados y ambos quedan grabados en BD, cuando en realidad uno debió de entrar y el siguiente debió de haber fallado como duplicado.

Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda!

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y porque no te sirve la clase cola de c#?

Comment: ¿Por qué los registros son idénticos? ¿Tienes algún tipo de restricción, una llave primaria, un indice único, etc? En caso contrario podrías realizar la busqueda del registro antes de hacer la inserción, para evitar el ingreso de duplicados.

Comment: Hola @JYass, gracias por tu respuesta. Los registros no son idénticos por indices únicos, sino mas bien por la información que poseen, lugar de donde vienen, lugar hacia a donde van, el mensaje que contiene. El problema es que se está buscando y comparando antes de la inserción, eso funciona... el problema es cuando dos mensajes idénticos ingresan en el segundo a la BD, porque no tienen contra quien comparar...

Comment: Cuando van a buscar no encuentran nada (al mismo tiempo) entonces ambos son ingresados. Si unos segundos después yo vuelvo a enviar el mismo mensaje, me da error porque si tiene contra que comparar... Pero cuando ingresan al mismo tiempo, ambos son ingresados. Mi idea es validar en una cola si hay mensajes idénticos y antes de enviarlos a la BD, hacer un pre filtro, y tiene que ser en una cola de RAM porque se requiere que sea rápido, que la validación sea en cuestión de milisegundos para que no afecte la productividad del producto.

Comment: @JassonSteCalderonVillalobos ¿Con que BD trabajas y que tipo de bloqueo tiene la tabla? Podrías aumentar el nivel de bloqueo, e intentar manejar transacciones para que una de las dos bloquee la tabla, la primera que llegue, así sea por milésimas  de segundo y antes del commit, verificar que haya sido ingresada.

Comment: @JassonSteCalderonVillalobos también podrías agregar una restricción unique para el conjunto de campos que te interesa que no se duplique.

Comment: @JYass, actualmente tiene bloqueo por tabla... Se me indicó también que se puede hacer bloqueo por registros para que pase exactamente esto que indicas, pero estuve investigando al respecto y no encuentro información funcional. Estoy utilizando Sybase 12.5 y Sybase 15.7... Te agradecería si con tu conocimiento me pudieras colaborar con información funcional para aplicar este bloqueo ya que según se me indica, puede ser una solución al problema.

Comment: @JassonSteCalderonVillalobos creo que debería ser al reves, bloquear por página o tabla y no por registro, porque la idea sería bloquearla completamente para evitar otra inserción. Si le das un sp_help a la tabla, que indica la sección de Lock scheme? En sybase 15 la modificación del tipo de bloqueo a la tabla debería ser con una instrucción así: alter table <nombre_tabla> lock allpages. Y manejar un begin tran antes del registro, realizarlo, verificar que haya sido insertado y luego la sentencia commit o un rollback si algo sale mal.¿Consideraste la opción del unique sobre los campos?

Comment: @JYass te contesto primero lo de unique. No me es funcionar colocar campos como unique ya que el servicio debería de permitir una inserción de registros idénticos siempre y cuando no estén dentro del rango de tiempo duplicado uno del otro... Te pongo un ejemplo: Digamos que el lapso de duplicado es de 30 minutos. Si entra el primer registro a las 10 AM y el segundo completamente idéntico entra a las 10:31 AM, ambos tienen que ser procesados, pero si el segundo registro entrara a las 10:10 AM entonces debería de ser rechazado por duplicidad.

Comment: @JYass Ahora con respecto a lo demás, cuando ejecuto el sp_help no existe ningún campo llamado "Lock scheme". A mi se me indicó que uno puede bloquear registros por un campo específico... Eso me serviría porque puedo bloquearlo por el emisor y si en el lapso de duplicidad entra algún mensaje de ese emisor pero es diferente entonces puede pasar, pero si es idéntico que se descarte por duplicidad. Se me explicó que si el registros está por páginas pueda ser que ese sea el problema por como funcionan los multi-hilos.